# Is the code sample about variable initialization correct?

Tags: c++

In the book rule 101 said that we should make sure `i` is initialed, the below code sample is bad right?

```
int i;
i=10;
```

What's more, isn't same between `int i=10` with `int i;i=10;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a very good habit to always initialize a variable as soon as you create it if possible. From my experience I've found it good to not only apply this rule to primitives, but objects themselves.

There are exceptions of course, but treat them as just that, exceptions.

If you have say, a sequence of numbers that you need to perform some type of operation on, you should make sure they all have *some* value assigned. If you try to perform any operations with the variables uninitialized, your program will simply crash. If however you assign them all a value upon creation, such as 0, or 1 even, then while your program can still have a serious issue debugging will be far easier.

With objects usually you can make your code better by having them initialized upon creation. For example, I was working on a tile map editor, which of course required tiles. When the map was to be created, it was initialize 'x' amount of tiles. I didn't leave them undefined. Other wise I wouldn't have been able to use them in any way until I did at whatever point. Not initializing them on the spot just wouldn't have made any sense.

You probably have come across pointers yet either, but I will mention them as well. In short a pointer is a variable that *drumroll* points to a variable. If you try to use a pointer without it pointing to something however, serious issues come up.

Guideline for pointers
  1.) If you are not going to assign a variable to the pointer (or allocate something) then make sure to assign it `NULL`
  2.) If you are not sure that the variable is pointing to something, then check if it's still NULL before trying to use it.
  3.) It's better if you know the pointer will be pointing to something for sure

Answer (score 3):

The book is giving good advice: you should initialise variables as soon as you create them if you can. It's not wrong to leave it uninitialised; but it is dangerous, since you might accidentally use it before assigning a value to it. This gives undefined behaviour, and could lead to bugs that are difficult and frustrating to find.

Comment: The compiler can often help you out there, too.

Comment: @chris: Indeed; one should always switch compiler warnings on, and they can often find mistakes like that. But they're not 100% reliable, so it's also a good idea to cultivate habits that avoid mistakes in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You did give `i` a valid value, but it's not initialized, it's assigned.

```
int i;    //uninitialized
i = 10;   //assignment
```

While

```
int i = 10;  //initialized
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are talking about local variables, because the assignment syntax does not work outside of a function. Although the compiler is smart enough to treat both statements in the same way, the second approach (i.e. `int i = 10`) is more readable.

The only exception from the rule that the declaration must be together with initialization is when you need to use the variable in the scope that is outside the initial assignment:

```
// It does not make sense to initialize i here, because no matter what its initial value is,
// the loop below will make an unconditional assignment to it.
int i;
do {
    cout << "Please enter a number (zero exits the program)" << endl;
    cin >> i;
} while (i != 0);
```

In other cases you should follow the rule and provide initialization as part of the declaration.